# TPS26601 Industrial eFUSE Circuit Design

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, schematics, circuit-protection

I have been designing a circuit for various `Power protections` like `overcurrent`, `overvoltage`, `undervoltage`, `reverse input polarity`. I have selected Industrial `eFUSE` [TPS26601](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2660.pdf). I have few queries regarding the circuit designing for TPS26601.

[image]

1. I am using a switch to pull-down `SHDN` pin for shutdown and leave it floating for normal operation as `Page 25` of the datasheet shows an internal pull-up resistor. Am I correct?
2. I know how to connect `RTN` pin of the IC but I am not sure why it has been there. The datasheet says it is for Device's Internal Reference. Why can't they have single pin (use GND for Device Internal Reference)?
3. The `Imon` pin of the IC is referred w.r.t to `RTN` pin. Imon pin outputs a current proportional (Reduced by certain factor) to current flowing through `OUT` pin. Connecting a resistor across `Imon` and `RTN` pin can convert the current to voltage and external ADC can calculate the system current. Since, `Imon` resistor is connected w.r.t `RTN` pin, I am not sure about using `opto-coupler`. Should I use it? Is it safe to connect directly to MCU?

Comment: 1.  If the datasheet shows a pullup, it's probably adequate unless you're in a high noise or high EMI environment.  2.  Sometimes you want a reference ground that has very little current flowing; the potential of your power ground might vary based on instantaneous current.  3.  If your MCU and chip are using the same ground and the voltages are compatible, it should work without an optocoupler.

Comment: The MCU will be using GND and TPS2660x will be using RTN.

Comment: Then it should work, just make sure the output is scaled to within the ADC range.  The RTN pin on that chip is the same as ground if you hook the supply up correctly.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis Thanks. You can change the comment to an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the datasheet shows a pullup, it's probably adequate unless you're in a high noise or high EMI environment.
2. Sometimes you want a reference ground that has very little current flowing; the potential of your power ground might vary based on instantaneous current.
3. If your MCU and chip are using the same ground and the voltages are compatible, it should work without an optocoupler.  Just make sure you don't violate the input voltage range.

Comment: It appears you have extensive knowledge of eFuses.  Would you happen to have extensive knowledge of proper integration (use, placement, parts selection) of eFuses into PCBA design? If so, are you available for paid consultation? Thank you, JRTayglo@gmail.com